# How big is the risk of agranulocytosis when taking metamizole?

Tags: side-effects, white-blood-count, otc-over-the-counter

In some countries, metamizole is completely banned because of the risk of agranulocytosis. In other countries (like mine) it is available as a prescription drug and I hear in other countries it is even available over the counter.

Given that it isn't taken long term (so, say, for less than two weeks at a time), how big is the risk of developing agranulocytosis, and how risky is that condition in those patients (meaning, can it usually be treated or does it lead to long-term complications / death)?

Answer (score 2):

This German report covering 22 years of prescribing and millions of prescriptions identified 161 cases of reported agranulocytosis of which there were 38 deaths, and 30% of the cases developed within 7 days and some even after 1-2 doses.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26169297

Based on this report the risk is minute but detectable, and perhaps one should consider using another drug with potentially less severe side effects.